# Clicking on textbox in the Dropdown is not working in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I had created a custom dropdown in react where on `onClick` the dropdown opens up and on `onBlur` closes it & I am controlling open and close of dropdown with react state. Now I wanted to toggle the Textbox when the user clicks the dropdown to enable the search feature. The issue is that, when I click the textbox, the `onBlur` event is firing up on the drop down and is getting closed. I tried to insert `e.stopProagation()` in the `onMouseDown` event but has no effect.

I am herewith sharing [my CodeSandBox URL.](https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-nash-8htfq?file=/src/CustomDropDown/CustomDropDown.js) Can you please have a look and let me know what can be done and help me in resolving the issue? I will be extremely thankful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the currentTarget to see if it contains the relatedTarget (the newly focused item)

```
onBlur={event => {
  if (!event.currentTarget.contains(event.relatedTarget)) {
    setDropDownOpen(false);
  }
}}
```

Comment: Hi this worked, thank you so much. Can you please explain what this statement `!event.currentTarget.contains(event.relatedTarget)`  means?

Comment: `event.currentTarget` is the element that the listener is attached to. `event.relatedTarget` is the newly focused element. Technically in this case `event.target` would've worked to because it refers to the dropdown element however `event.relatedTarget` referred directly to input that was being clicked.

The logic happening is: if the dropdown element does not contain the newly focused element than close the dropdown

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining me in detail. I had never dwelled deep into the events and your answer, I will make note of it. Have a great day ahead...!!

Answer (score 2):

I have created a very simple demo that demonstrates how you can solve this issue ([See sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-firefly-ynyjq?file=/src/App.js)).

In a nutshell, I created another hook that checks whether the input focus is currently active or not. If it is, then don't close the div on blur.

Comment: Hi Eliya, thank you for the answer. So you are trying to control the dropdown based on the blur events on input field. I have a question : ` onClick={() => isInputFocus && setOpen(false)}>` for the onclick event you wrote on the div, say I hit the toggle button which makes the `isOpen` as true.  But since you are not stopping the event bubbling, the the outer div too tries to execute the click event, in that case it should execute the `setOpen(false)` and should again toggle it, but it's not happening. Can you please explain this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one suggestion:
Use `eventListner`

- `addEventlistener` on componentDidMount
- `removeEventlistener` onClick
- `addEventlistener` again when you select the item from dropdown.